# Reassign variable in with-block

Tags: python

Is it possible to reassign the object of a with-block prior to exiting the block?

#### Specific use case

I interact with an FTP server that occasionally drops connections mid-transfer, and IT is not willing to do anything about it. As a workaround for my own tools, I'm using a wrapper that will retry transfers a few times before giving up:

```
def retry(conn, max_tries=3, **kwargs):
    this_try = 1
    while (this_try <= max_tries):
        try:
            # upload / download / whatever
            return conn
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            conn.quit()
            time.sleep(60)
            conn = ftplib.FTP(**kwargs)
            this_try += 1
```

This wrapper works fine, but doesn't doesn't appear to be usable inside a `with` block, like normal FTP connections can be used. If the `except` clause is ever hit, the connection will be re-established, but on exiting the `with` block, python will attempt to close the original `conn`, not the new one:

```
with ftplib.FTP(**kwargs) as conn:
    conn = retry(conn, **kwargs)
```

This can be demonstrated with a custom context manager, showing that python calls `__exit__()` from the original object, even if the variable is reassigned mid-block:

```
>>> class Echo(object):
...     def __enter__(self):
...             print('entering ' + repr(self))
...             return self
...     def __exit__(self, *args):
...             print('exiting ' + repr(self))
...
>>> with Echo() as e:
...     e = Echo()
...
entering <__main__.Echo object at 0x026C14F0>
exiting <__main__.Echo object at 0x026C14F0>
>>> e
<__main__.Echo object at 0x026C1410>
```

How can I reassign `conn` inside the `with` block so that python calls the `__exit__()` method on the latest object, instead of the original one? Is such a thing even possible, or am I forced to go without `with` blocks and have to remember to call `conn.quit()` everywhere?

If it matters, I'd like something compatible with both python 2 and 3. If a solution is not compatible with both, then I would prefer a python 3-specific solution over a python 2-specific solution

Comment: I doubt you can. `conn` is just a name that refers to an object somewhere in memory, if you assign it to something else then it just refers to another object instead. You could come up with another solution instead, such as encapsulating your code that uploads/downloads in a function and decorate it with a function similar to your `retry` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pieces from several other answers, I've restructured the retry logic into a wrapper class that can be used as a context manager. This way I can recreate the FTP instance as needed, without altering the objected used in a `with` block. Normal `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` events from the `with` block are passed down to the FTP instance, and during recreation these methods are explicitly called. Below is the basic framework; I've cut out a lot of the actual FTP stuff so that piece won't work as-is, but the context manager stuff is all here:

```
class RetryClient():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.conn = get_conn(**kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn.__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.conn.__exit__(*args)

    def _reconnect(self):
        self.conn.__exit__()
        time.sleep(60)
        self.conn = get_conn(**self.kwargs)
        self.conn.__enter__()

    def upload(self, src, ...):
        this_try = 1
        while (this_try <= max_tries):
            try:
                with open(src, 'rb') as fh:
                    self.conn.storbinary('STOR ' + src, fh.read)
            except ftplib.all_errors:
                this_try += 1
                self._reconnect()
```

```
with RetryClient() as rc:
    for inode in os.listdir('.'):
        rc.upload(inode)
```

I've done some basic testing and it appears to be behaving as expected, at least for exceptions due to invalid permissions or open file handles. I don't have a way to test the dropped FTP connections, so I'll just need to wait for it to happen again and see how this handles it.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your general question, no you cannot, as shown in [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) "Specification: The with statement". The variable `e` in your context is saved into an internal variable which is used at tear-down time.
For the specific FTP connection, some other options have been proposed in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

`__enter__` can return any object not only `self`. I.e. `e` is a normal variable and `__exit__` is the method of the same object, as was called `__enter__`.

As for your problem, you could call `connect` and `login` to reconnect to the server with the same FTP-instance:

```
def retry(conn, user, passwd):
    conn.connect()
    conn.login(user, passwd)
```

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.connect) say that `connect` and `login` should only be called once; they don't say anything about supporting multiple calls in case of failure or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change which `__exit__` method gets called. You have to restructure your code.

There are two problems with trying to reassign the `with` target. First, `with` is designed to tear down the resources it set up, and there isn't much of a reason for the design to let you interfere with that. Second, the `with` target doesn't even have to be the actual context manager. For example, if you use `with contextlib.closing(something) as thing`, `thing` most likely isn't even a valid context manager. The object whose `__exit__` method gets called is some other object entirely.

Reassigning the `with` is the wrong way to go about this. Instead, restructure your retry logic. For example, instead of having `retry` take a connection and possibly return a different one, have it create the initial connection too, and use `retry` as a context manager. (I'm not familiar with FTP or ftplib, so this might not be the best design for this particular use case):

```
def retry(max_tries=3, **kwargs):
    for try in range(max_tries):
        conn = ftplib.FTP(**kwargs)
        try:
            # upload / download / whatever
            return conn
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            conn.quit()
            time.sleep(60)
    raise AppropriateError

with retry(...) as conn:
    ...
```

Comment: I agree witht the restructure, but `retry` isn't a valid context manager in this example

Comment: @BrendanAbel: It's not? Is `ftplib.FTP` one of those cases where `__enter__` doesn't return `self`?

Comment: To use `with retry(...)`, `retry` has to be a context manager object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, or a function generator that uses the[`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator

Comment: @BrendanAbel: The returned object needs to be a context manager, and it is, isn't it? It's an `ftplib.FTP` instance. Maybe you're misunderstanding something. For example, if you did `def my_open(*args, **kwargs): return open(*args, **kwargs)`, then `my_open(filename)` would be a perfectly valid context manager. Try it!

Comment: All the work for this happens in the retry function before the `with` block is entered, so this would become `with retry(...) as conn: pass`.  the same 2 lines could be used for `conn = retry(...); conn.quit()` which would be more clear as to what is happening.

Comment: @Steve: So you're not doing anything in the `with` block besides the `retry` call? That just makes your original code structure *more* confusing. I thought you wanted to retry the connection until it worked and then do something useful in the `with` block, but if all the work happens in `retry`, the `with` is pointless.

Comment: The point of the `with` block is to invoke the `__exit__()` method on the FTP instance to properly close the connection without me having to remember to call `conn.quit()` everytime I use it.  the retry piece is because the server is unreliable, and I want it to attempt the transfer again before crashing.

Comment: @Steve: But you still end up needing to call `quit` explicitly in the `except` block, so the `with` isn't helping you. It would have been better to put a `with` *inside* `retry` if that was your intention.

Comment: see my other answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36575911/1026333
the wrapper class passes `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` events to the FTP connection, so I can still use a `with` block for proper setup and teardown.  It's true the class needs to explicitly call some things during the recreation, but thats the point of classes; now that it's done once, I can reuse the class as much as I want and don't have to worry about these issues anymore